# Highchart, how to vertically align in the middle a line?

Tags: highcharts

I tried with several approaches but without success (through translateY in CSS, graphic.translate ecc).

Do you know how to move the line, together with its relative points and tooltips vertically in the middle independently by its Y values?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MrFabio80/me48gs6y/

Code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointStart: 1
        }
    },

    series: [{
            type: 'column',
            data: [100, 45, 80, 25, 12, 87],
            name: 'Column'
        },

        {
            type: 'spline',
            name: 'Trend',
            data: [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 0],
            color: '#588BDC',
            marker: {
                fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
                lineWidth: 2,
                lineColor: null, // inherit from series
                width: 8,
                height: 8
            }

        }
    ]
});
```

The chart should look like in the screenshot below:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the expected chart? Could you add an image or better describe which line you are referring to?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, traveling abroad.. I update the post with a screenshot! Thanks

Comment: If you want points to be seen as with the same values then you could set the same values: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/21oznhk4/ If you want points to have additional values, like customExtraInfo or anything really, then you could add it but use the y values for series and point plotting to keep the chart simple. Is this what you are looking for or could you provide more info?

Comment: I think you just solved, I just left the "real" values for the line chart in the tooltip with a proper formatter function! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Feel free to add it as answer so I can mark it as the Solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want points to be seen as with the same values then you could set the same values:

If you want points to have additional values, like customExtraInfo or anything really, then you could add it but use the y values for series and point plotting to keep the chart simple.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/21oznhk4/1/

Relevant tooltip options are [`formatter`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter), [`pointFormat`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormat), etc.